# What could have happened to my website files on my google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ckan

I was using google cloud platform to host a ckan based website. The website had a file library with about 5 gigs of documents. Our project got put on hold and I removed billing on the website about 8 months ago. Now we are trying to migrate the data, but when I look at the project in Google Cloud Platform, there are no compute instances, buckets or files under the various storage modules. I cannot find the 5gigs of files we uploaded and filed by various categories on the ckan website. What could have happened to them? I'm not very experience with this platform and a bit confused. Is there any way for me to recover my data?

Comment: what did you do? Which command? on what?

Comment: My colleague, just removed his billing so that the website was no longer live. He helped set it up and doesn't recall removing or deleting anything, but the virtual machine and files are no longer there.

Comment: If you remove your biling account on a project you lost all the resources that cost. Have a look to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_elELrPReWU Try to attach a new billing account and see if your resource are back again. Else, try to contact the support. Not sure on what next...

Comment: Thanks. I checked with Google tech support and indeed the assets get deleted after 30 days and are not recoverable. Any idea of Google Cloud keeps automatic backups stored somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As the GCP [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/restart-services#restart_services_that_were_shut_down) indicates, if your billing account remains invalid for a protracted period, some resources might be removed from the projects associated with your account. For example, if you use Google Cloud, your Compute Engine resources might be removed.

Removed resources are not recoverable, the best option you had was to review your case with tech support and have a more specific answer, I noticed that there isn't any way to recover resources 30 days later it had been removed, this is also described in [Data deletion](https://cloud.google.com/terms/data-processing-terms#6.-data-deletion) term, including existing copies.